# Using Network Analysis in SQL subset dataframe

Tags: sql, database, network-analysis

I'm working with Dune Analytics - a platform that lets you use SQL to analyze blockchain data. My end goal is to export a dataframe of transactions and run network analysis on Python. Dune make you pay to export data, so I'm trying to only pull the data I need.

The data: People send transactions from one address to another, so the only columns I care about are Senders and Receivers of transactions.

The problem: I am trying to separate out people who are connected to a broader network from people who only interact with one other person.

My question:
What is a sql query that will give me a list of all isolated pairs of sends and receivers. To formalize the conditions:

1. A sends a transaction to B
2. A DOES NOT send a transaction anyone else
3. B DOES NOT send a transaction to anyone else
4. B DOES NOT receive a transaction anyone else

Writing a query for a specific A and B isn't translating into a general query which gives me a list of all wallets who only sent transactions to one other person and not receive transactions from anyone else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you'd like to see the actual dataframe I'm working with go [here](https://dune.com/queries/2030714/3361639)

Answer (score 1):

So i think I have an answer, but would love for anyone to review or confirm if this makes sense.

I made a dataframe for any wallet that was connected to 2 or more wallets. I then said if anyone was connected to any of those wallets, it would be included in the network. You can see in the sql code below how I got to that answer. Hopefully it makes sense!!

```
WITH
  core_nrk AS (
  (SELECT 'senders' AS category, "from" AS address,COUNT(*) AS wallet_count 
  FROM (SELECT "from",to FROM ethereum.transactions WHERE block_time > DATE_TRUNC('day', NOW() - INTERVAL '3' day) AND success = TRUE GROUP BY 1, 2) /* pull from a dataframe of all transactions from the past 3 days. */
      GROUP BY 1,2
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) /* select all rows that have a count of ocnencted wallets of > 1, segmented senders and recievers. */
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'reciever' AS category,to AS address, COUNT(*) AS wallet_count
      FROM (SELECT "from", to FROM ethereum.transactions WHERE block_time > DATE_TRUNC('day', NOW() - INTERVAL '3' day) AND success = TRUE  GROUP BY 1,2) 
      GROUP BY 1, 2
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) /* select all rows that have a count of ocnencted wallets of > 1, segmented senders and recievers.~ */)
      
SELECT
  "from",
  to,
  SUM(CAST(value AS DOUBLE)) AS eth,
  COUNT(*) as count_tx
FROM
  ethereum.transactions
WHERE
  block_time > DATE_TRUNC('day', NOW() - INTERVAL '3' day)
  AND success = TRUE
  AND ("from" IN (SELECT address FROM core_nrk ) OR to IN ( SELECT address FROM core_nrk))
GROUP BY 1,2
```